# Crear y graficar arreglo de pendientes entre puntos

Tags: python, array, matplotlib, revisión-de-código, numpy

Buenas tardes a todos, estoy tratando de crear un array con `numpy` que contenga la pendiente entre cada uno de los puntos realizados con los arrays `x` e `y` para finalmente graficarlos con `matplotlib`.

Estos son los pasos que sigo actualmente:

**1.** Calculo la pendiente para cada uno de los puntos.

**2.** Agrego cada pendiente calculada a una lista.

**3.** La lista que resulta la transformo en un array de `numpy`.

**4.** Gráfico ese array con matplotlib.

Este es mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3,2,1,0])
lista = []
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    dy = (y[i+1]-y[i]) / (x[i+1] - x[i])
    lista.append(dy)
pendiente = np.asarray(lista)
ejex = len(x)-1
plt.plot(ejex,pendiente,'-m')
plt.show()
```

¿Alguien conoce una mejor forma de realizar esto?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [np.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) para las diferencias y luego hacer la división. El resultado es un `numpy.ndarray`, así que no tienes que convertirlo.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3,2,1,0])
pendiente = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)
plt.plot(pendiente, '-m')
plt.show()
```